# How does MoveIt! CollisionPlugin interact with Moveit?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, collision, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to write a plugin for collision detection for Moveit, and I've checked out their page here:
https://moveit.ros.org/documentation/plugins/#collisionplugin

However, it's not clear to me how the plugin is called or what methods need to be supplied. It's not clear to me how a `checkCollision` call ends up getting to the plugin. The only member function appears to be `initialize`. Should I also be implementing versions of the classes in the template of the allocator ( `MyCollisionWorld, MyCollisionRobot`)?

It's unclear to me how this all architecturally fits into Moveit and what interacts with it. I'm attempting to implement a plugin which allows making decisions about collisions not by the number of contacts, but as having each contact having a cost (such that links in the robot can collide and move into the space of some objects). It's not clear if the API for the plugin allows this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321526/how-does-moveit!-collisionplugin-interact-with-moveit?/) by [ssnover](https://answers.ros.org/users/39852/ssnover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2019-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yeah, the documentation linked isn't the most detailed (feel free to make [an issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit.ros.org/issues), I'd like to fix this at some point). You're correct in that the actual interfaces you need to be implementing is [collision_robot](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/7fdc7f35f763c5e6784b5a72665188b2426fc009/moveit_core/collision_detection/include/moveit/collision_detection/collision_robot.h#L54), and [collision_world](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/7fdc7f35f763c5e6784b5a72665188b2426fc009/moveit_core/collision_detection/include/moveit/collision_detection/collision_world.h#L55). Once you have implemented those two classes, you should be able to copy-paste the ["Typical Usage"](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/7fdc7f35f763c5e6784b5a72665188b2426fc009/moveit_core/collision_detection/include/moveit/collision_detection/collision_plugin.h#L50) (that is the main focus of the current documentation).

As for what interacts with the collision checker, it's mostly the [Planning Scene](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/874a1d95deaa5087059cf4a1e0eec5b883de9340/moveit_core/planning_scene/src/planning_scene.cpp#L320) and by extension the [Motion Planners](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/874a1d95deaa5087059cf4a1e0eec5b883de9340/moveit_planners) that use the planning scene to avoid objects.

The [CollisionResult](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/874a1d95deaa5087059cf4a1e0eec5b883de9340/moveit_core/collision_detection/include/moveit/collision_detection/collision_common.h#L137) object should be enough to implement what you're talking about, but I'd heavily suggest integrating this collision checker with a motion planner yourself, from your description I don't think the default motion planners would take advantage of this special collision information.

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2019-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1